# Syntax sugar for variable replacement with `round`

Tags: ruby

We have do-and-replace functions like `map!`, `reject!`, `reverse!`, `rotate!`. Also we have binary operations in short form like `+=`, `-=`.

Do we have something for mathematical `round`? We need to use `a = a.round`, and it's a bit weird for me to repeat the variable name. Do you know how to shorten it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, smart guys have already explained, why there is no syntactic sugar for `Float#round`. Just out of curiosity I’m gonna show, how you might implement this sugar yourself [partially]. Since `Float` class has no `~@` method defined, and you do rounding quite often, you might monkeypatch `Float` class:

```
class Float
  def ~@
    self.round # self is redundant, left just for clarity
  end
end
```

or, in this simple case, just (credits to @sawa):

```
alias_method :~@, :round
```

and now:

```
~5.2
#⇒ 5
a = 2.45 && ~a
#⇒ 2
```

Since `Numeric`s are immutable, it’s still impossible to modify it inplace, but the above might save you four keyboard hits per rounding.

Comment: Why not write `alias ~@ round`?

Comment: `alias` is good unless one wants to tune the solution. E.g. `Float#round` accepts a parameter etc. I tried to show the skeleton that might be improved further. But you’re right, alias should be added to an answer. I’ll do.

Answer (score 2):

As for destructive methods, it is impossible since numerals are immutable, and it would not make sense. Would you want a numeral `5.2` that behaves as `5`?

As for syntax sugar, it would be a mess if every single method had one. So there isn't. And since syntax sugar is defined in the core level, you cannot do anything in an ordinary Ruby script to create a new one.

Comment: Actually, there are some proposals on the Ruby bug tracker, I think. Stuff like `a .= round` or `a =.round`. I'm not sure that's an improvement, though.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You found it? I think that is my proposal.

Comment: That's bad. 'a.round!' like they did with arrays would be a good solution

Comment: @AKovtunov You still don't understand my answer.

Comment: @sawa no, I've got it. And it's sad that right now we can do nothing except that monkeypatching. But I really like that methods so it's like a dream :)

Comment: @AKovtunov `a.round!`is **not** a good solution, it is even not a solution at all, since it is impossible to mutate _the type (class) of a variable_. `map!` and company is possible because the object type remains the same (`Array`.) To make it clear for you: one might paint a red chair to make it blue, but there is no action to make an apple out from the chair.

Comment: @mudasobwa got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's numeric types are immutable: they are value objects.  Therefore you won't find any methods that mutate a number in place.

Because the numeric types are immutable, certain optimizations are possible that would not be possible with mutable numbers.  In c-ruby, for example, a *reference*, which may point to any kind of object, is normally a pointer to an object.  But if the reference is to a Fixnum, then the reference *contains* the integer itself, rather than pointing to an instance of Fixnum.  Ruby does a number of magic tricks to hide this optimization, making it appear that an integer really is an instance of a Fixnum.

To make numbers mutable would make this optimization impossible, so I don't expect that Ruby will ever have mutable numeric types.